# Remote music management software recommendation

Tags: audio, music, mp3

I would like a good recommendation for music playback software having the ability to remote control the music playing.

The scenario is: 
Setup some music clients (PCs) with that software which will playback continuously given playlists with MP3 tracks. I want to be able to change the playlist at anytime without interruption, do that remotely and the clients sync to this change.

The tracks and playlists may be managed from an admin panel. All tracks must be locally saved on client and not stream for not consuming bandwidth. That is, if a new track is added to a playlist, the first time this track is requested it should be downloaded and saved to client (sync).

I want to avoid streaming scenario. The clients should have locally saved the tracks needed for playback as defined in playlist.
Scheduling of the music playing in time frames is also an option to be included. It should support start and end times by playlist.

Comment: When you say 'remote', do you mean across the Internet, or on the same network?

Comment: Across the internet not a LAN. I am thinking of an administration panel where I specify the lists and the tracks. When a new track is added this will have to be downloaded (synced) to each client.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer because I was answering the wrong question!